# Azure DevOps: Incomplete list of related workitems in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1 running locally on our server.

When we commit, we always add a link to one or more associated workitems. The workitems are correctly linked to a commit. So far, so good.

I have a build pipeline that is running for the first time. There is no previous build. When running the pipeline, some of our workitems are not added to the list of related workitems.

[image: Screenshot Build Pipeline]

DevOps lists 50+ items. To be exact, there are 78 items. However, when I manually check the commit history, I find 186 work items associated with at least one commit. What could be the reason for 108 workitems missing from this list? I could not find anything that the missing workitems have in common. How does DevOps find the related workitems? Is there a way to debug this process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken with Microsoft about this.

I have an incomplete list of related work items in my build pipeline because the number of changes linked with a pipeline execution is limited to 250:
[image]

Let's say we have implemented a very important "Feature A". Now we continue working and make 250 more changes without ever mentioning "Feature A" again. In this case, when we run a build pipeline, "Feature A" will never be part of the related work items. This is especially bad if the list of related work items is later used, for example, to create release notes.

In my opinion, it is very dangerous and misleading that there is such a limit.

The limit for 250 changes was defined by the product group and is basically a threshold to prevent performance degradation.

I sincerely hope that Microsoft will remove this limit.